# Moving Divs using Css or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I have a css div that I would like to MOVE. Css transitions and Jquery slide up and down expand or decrease the element size. Jquery animate left and right is the best I have found so far. However i would also like to move up and down. Can you do that with Jquery animate? If so how. If not is there a way to do this using Javascript Jquery or Css

This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .purplecircle {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
                -moz-border-radius: 50px;
                border-radius: 50px;
                background:#C0F;
                position:absolute;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#purplecircle1").animate({left: '96%'});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <div class="purplecircle" id="purplecircle1"></div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What HTML do you have, what CSS, how far did you get with your jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Moving the element 96% left doesn't really work when the element has no starting point (there's no left position set initially) and the parent element has no width ?

Comment: I did 96% because 100% goes off the page. I don't need to specify a starting spot because it goes left as a default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the element up/down you can use either the `top` or `bottom` properties of the JQuery `animate` function. For example to move the element down you can do:

```
$("#purplecircle1").animate({top: '-x%'});
```

and similarly to move the element up:

```
$("#purplecircle1").animate({top: 'x%'});
```

Where `x` is the integer value you wish to move the value by. You can omit the % unit to use pixels.

Answer (score 0):

To move up and down you can use top or bottom variables instead of left like: `jQuery("#purplecircle1").animate({top: '50%'});`

You can change value according to your requirement.